# Is it possible to write subqueries with LinQ?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, subquery

Suppose that I have this two tables:

- TableA(IDTableA, ...)
- TableB(IDTableB, IDTableA, ...)

I would like a subquery with LinQ like this:

```
select * 
from MytableA 
where IDTableA = (select IDTable A From TableB where IDTableB = 123);
```

I am trying something like this:

```
MytableA myTableAEntity = dbContext.MytableA
.Where(x=>x.IDTableA == dbContext.MytableB.Where(y=>y.IDTableB == 123).SingleOrDefault();
```

But I have an error that says that I can't cast `IQueryable<long>` into a long.

Is it possible to do something like that?

Thank so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first `Where` clause you are testing equality of incompatible types of `long` and `MytableB`.

You have to select `IDTableA` in your subquery before comparing:

```
IEnumerable<MytableA> matchedTableAs = dbContext.MytableA
    .Where(x=>x.IDTableA == dbContext.MytableB.Where(y=>y.IDTableB == 123)
        .Select(b => b.IDTableA).SingleOrDefault());
```

Comment: But I think with this solution that the SingleOrDefault do a quiery to database and then the main where another query, so I need two trip to the database. I would like to avoid this and make only one trip.

Comment: No, EF generates one SQL statement for this.

Comment: And there is any way to check if EF does two trips or only one? This question is to learn how to depure my code.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía You can use LINQpad to view the generated SQL. Or use  the `ToTraceString()` method described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1412902/2419531.